# NGINX Sporadic/Random 502 Bad Gateway - .NET Core Backend - Low to zero request_time

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We've been getting chunks of 502s across our application servers sporadically. I attempted to scale up the servers (from t3.medium to t3.large) but I fear it's a deeper issue than scaling.

The affected servers run NGINX as a reverse proxy and .NET Core services.

We do do downtime-less deployments by having 2 services running as one winds down. up-stores-a and up-stores-b, and nginx routes requests to the other one once deployment completes. The "Bad Gateway" issues don't happen during deployments which is a huge headscratcher why the upstream name is coming into play, but I wanted to provide background anyways.

Here's the server setup (with some info removed):

```
upstream up-stores-a {
     server 127.0.0.1:51285;
     server 127.0.0.1:51284 backup;
     keepalive 32;
}

upstream up-stores-b {
     server 127.0.0.1:51284;
     server 127.0.0.1:51285 backup;
     keepalive 32;
}

server {
    server_name stores.{{url}};
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://up-stores-a;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access-stores.log upstreamlog;
    }
}
```

Here's a chunk of logs:

```
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:21 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: 127.0.0.1:51285, up-stores-a: GET /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 1.004, 0.000 msec 1586889741.801 request_time 1.006
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:21 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: 127.0.0.1:51285, up-stores-a: GET /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.556, 0.000 msec 1586889741.804 request_time 0.558
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:21 +0000] {{ip}}- - - {{url}} {{url}} to: 127.0.0.1:51285, up-stores-a: GET /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.812, 0.000 msec 1586889741.804 request_time 0.817
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:21 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: 127.0.0.1:51285, up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.700, 0.000 msec 1586889741.805 request_time 0.707
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:21 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: 127.0.0.1:51285, up-stores-a: GET /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.500, 0.000 msec 1586889741.805 request_time 0.503
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:21 +0000] {{ip}}- - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889741.861 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:21 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889741.885 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:21 +0000] {{ip}}- - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: GET /cc-small-many-sku/33249675870348,33249887387788,32995463921804 HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889741.889 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:21 +0000] {{ip}}- - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: GET /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889741.913 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:21 +0000] {{ip}}- - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: GET /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889741.979 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:22 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889742.079 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:22 +0000] {{ip}}- - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889742.088 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:22 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small-many-sku/159958564873 HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889742.090 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:22 +0000] {{ip}}- - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small-many-sku/15937965064282,15937965097050 HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889742.274 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:22 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small-many-sku/31700323500129 HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889742.288 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:22 +0000] {{ip}}- - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: GET /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889742.373 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:22 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small-many-sku/18157812801 HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889742.437 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:22 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889742.461 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:22 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889742.488 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:22 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889742.517 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:22 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889742.603 request_time 0.000
[14/Apr/2020:18:42:23 +0000] {{ip}} - - - {{url}} {{url}} to: up-stores-a: OPTIONS /cc-small/none HTTP/1.1 502 upstream_response_time 0.000 msec 1586889743.132 request_time 0.000
```

I also did find that `grep " up-stores-a" access-stores.log` returned all 502s, so it seems like when the "to" part contains up-stores-a, it fails. Going to scale up more and see if that helps, but there weren't any CPU spikes, memory spikes, network spikes, or any other metric that can point to a root cause of why the .net core service wouldn't be returning. According to the access logs, there weren't any more requests that minute that errors happened than any other minute without errors.

Also, is it strange that the request time is 0.000 and it fails? As if it didn't even try.

Is there any other data I can collect to help me find the root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many other questions have been answered, it's not NGINX causing the problem, it's the service.

Upgrading to dotnet core 3 and getting redis timeouts under control proved to be the winning combination here. I guess dotnet core 3 has some stability fixes that prevent 502s.